# Change xml attribute value with XPath with vtd-xml Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, vtd-xml

I have to set the value of "count" attribute in this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task>
   <trigger count="myCount" interval="myInterval"/>
   <property name="myName" value="myValue"/>
   <property name="mySecondName"value="mySecondValue">
</task>
```

i'd like to change myCount value with "Foo" with a code like this (VTDXML library):

```
            String count  = "Foo";
            if (vg.parseFile("C:\\Users\\_myPath_\\myFile.xml", true)) {
                VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
                ap.bind(vn);
                xm.bind(vn);
                ap.selectXPath("/*[name()='task']/*[name()='trigger']");
                int i=0;
                while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
                    xm.insertAfterHead(count);
                }
                xm.output("C:\\Users\\_myPath_\\myFileWithFoo.xml");
                System.out.println(vg);
            }
```

In this way i obtain instead

```
  <trigger count="myCount" interval="myInterval">Foo</trigger>
```

that is not my goal, because what i want is

```
  <trigger count="Foo" interval="myInterval"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution applied for changing the content of both "count" and "interval":

```
           String count= "Foo";
           String interval= "Dummy";       
           String attribute  = " count=\""+ foo + "\" interval=\""+ interval+"\"";
            if (vg.parseFile("C:\\Users\\_myPath_\\myFile.xml", true)) {
                VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
                ap.bind(vn);
                xm.bind(vn);
                ap.selectXPath("/*[name()='task']/*[name()='trigger']");
                int i=0;
                while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
                    xm.insertAttribute(attribute);
                }
                xm.output("C:\\Users\\_myPath_\\myFileWithFoo.xml");
                System.out.println(vg+attribute);
            }
```

And the result is:

```
 <trigger count="Foo" interval="Dummy" />
```

I used method insertAttribute that appends my string to the name of the node (trigger).

I know this is an horrible solution, but it works fine.

Comment: your xpath is weird.. why not just use /task/trigger?

Comment: Because i have xmlns in task tag, and this is the only way i can reach this goal... maybe there are other solutions, but as i said in the former comment, i'll be on the right computer on monday and i'll explain everything. Thank you vtd-xml-author, your work is very very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath should be /task/trigger/@count

the statement for change attr value is xmlModifier.updateToken(i+1)

Below is a sample without resorting to namespaces...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import com.ximpleware.*;

public class updateAttrVal2 {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException,UnsupportedEncodingException,IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        String xml="<task xmlns='ns1' xmlns:abc='ns2'><abc:trigger count=\"myCount\" interval=\"myInterval\"/></task>";
        vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes());
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn=vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/task/trigger/@count");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.updateToken(i+1, "Count");
        }
        XMLByteOutputStream xms = new XMLByteOutputStream(xm.getUpdatedDocumentSize());
        xm.output(xms);
        System.out.println(xms.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but i had an error. Now i'm not on the pc where i have my development, i will be more precise during next monday, thank you.

Comment: you can turn off the namespace awareness... this will work

Comment: I have to hold namespaces information, this are wso2 esb configuration xml, so i can't turn them off. I tried with updateToken(i+1, "myCount") but it doesn't work, trigger tag remains blank

Comment: I will post a snippet piece soon... stay tuned